# Operator from Ethereum contract _;

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts

Sorry if it is duplicated question.
What does "_" operator make?

This code is from Ethereum contract manual:
https://ethereum.org/token#deploying

```
contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is resolved in this other site. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/are-underscores-in-modifiers-code-or-are-they-just-meant-to-look-cool?newreg=95181540ee304308aa071f6a2b97d87f

Answer (score 0):

It is used inside modifiers.

> "The function body is inserted where the special symbol "_" in the
>   definition of a modifier appears."

Reference: 
[Contracts — Solidity 0.4.19 documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers)

And in case it is used only once in a modifier, you can see it as following:
After the return variables are assigned, the `_` returns the control flow to what is next to the current modifier (next to the current modifier could be the next modifier or the function).

You can see a detailed explanation and example in the answer at:
[Are underscores `_` in modifiers code or are they just meant to look cool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/are-underscores-in-modifiers-code-or-are-they-just-meant-to-look-cool?newreg=95181540ee304308aa071f6a2b97d87f)

Answer (score 0):

Modifiers are used to enforce pre/post-conditions on the execution of a function.

The `_` operator is a shorthand that represents *the actual code of the function that you are "modifying"*.

So in your code, every time that `transferOwnership` is invoked, the `onlyOwner` modifyer will get into play first.

- If you are not the owner, the execution will just `throw`, roll everything back and exit.
- If you are the owner, the control flow will reach the `_` operator, so the `transferOwnership` statements will be executed.